# Not able to post data to data base Entity Framework Blazor App

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I am trying to add form data to database. I am using the entity framework in a blazor application. I am able to retrieve data but not able to add and update.

```
@using ForAllSeniorCitizens.Models

@inject IDonorService donorService
@inject FASCCDbContext _db

<div class="dashheader d-flex align-items-center pl-4 py-2 bg-cta text-light">
    <MatIcon Class="mr-2" Icon="@MatIconNames.Local_florist"></MatIcon> <MatH5 Class="mb-0">Donor Info</MatH5>
</div>

<div class="content p-4 container">
    <div class="AddDonor">
        <div class="mat-layout-grid">
            <div class="mat-layout-grid-inner">
                <div class="mat-layout-grid-cell mat-layout-grid-cell-span-6">
                    <MatH4>Add a donor here before recording their donation at <a href="#">Cash Donations</a> or <a href="#">Item Donations</a></MatH4>
                </div>
                <div class="mat-layout-grid-cell mat-layout-grid-cell-span-6">
                    <EditForm Model="@donor" OnValidSubmit="AddDonor">
                        <DataAnnotationsValidator />

                        <MatTextField Label="First Name" @bind-Value="@donor.FirstName" FullWidth="true"></MatTextField>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => donor.FirstName)" />

                        <MatTextField Label="Middle Name" @bind-Value="@donor.MiddleName" FullWidth="true"></MatTextField>


                        <MatTextField Label="First Name" @bind-Value="@donor.LastName" FullWidth="true"></MatTextField>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => donor.LastName)" />

                        <MatTextField Label="Email" @bind-Value="@donor.Email" FullWidth="true"></MatTextField>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => donor.LastName)" />

                        <MatTextField Label="Phone Number" @bind-Value="@donor.PhoneNumber" FullWidth="true"></MatTextField>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => donor.PhoneNumber)" />

                        <MatButton Type="submit">Add</MatButton>
                    </EditForm>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>


@code {
    Donor donor = new();

    private async Task AddDonor()
    {
        //await donorService.Add(donor);
        //StateHasChanged();

        donor.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        donor.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;

        _db.Donors.Add(donor);

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        base.StateHasChanged();
    }   

}
```

I put breakpoints to check if the model is being populated, and it is. The data is just not updating to database. No errors whatsoever.

Comment: Hi @Smith Waliko Msiska, I have tested the code and it could be added to the database successfully. Could you please check the `Output` panel in visual studio if it makes any error when save this data? Also, could you please share your model design and DbContext?

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed adding to the database, but blazor's stateHasChanged was not re-rendering the page.

Comment: Hi @Smith Waliko Msiska, What's the page you want to display?

Comment: Same page, I want the names to refresh to show that a new name has been added.

Comment: @Rena removed removed the code that pulls data from the database since the code is working, but not re-rendering when I call statehaschanged.

Comment: Hi @Smith Waliko Msiska, your view is just an Add operation view. I fill in the form and get into AddDonor method, it will still keep the data I fill in the form. What you did seems to render the data list with the new added data. But your shared code do not have such code to display data.